# Is worst case analysis not equal to asymptotic bounds

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Can someone explain to me why this is true. I heard a professor mention this is his lecture

Comment: I bet you didn't know there was another site for that. It's called http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ and everybody there asks questions just like yours!

Comment: @Elijah: That's a very dubious statement as questions just like this are off topic there. Apparently you have neither looked at the questions asked on cstheory nor read its FAQ, which clearly states that the site is for research-level questions only.

Comment: Well, this particular question is a bit off, you are right.

Comment: I agree with sepp2k. That is THE ONLY reason i did not post it there.  @Elijah: Please spend some time reading all the faqs of the websites for stack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two notions are orthogonal.

You can have *worst case asymptotics*. If `f(n)` denotes the worst case time taken by a given algorithm with input `n`, you can have eg. `f(n) = O(n^3)` or other asymptotic upper bounds of the worst case time complexity.

Likewise, you can have `g(n) = O(n^2 log n)` where `g(n)` is the average time taken by the same algorithm with (say) uniformly distributed (random) inputs of size `n`.

Or you can have `h(n) = O(n)` where `h(n)` is the average time taken by the same algorithm with particularly distributed random inputs of size `n` (eg. almost sorted sequences for a sorting algorithm).

Asymptotic notation is a "measure". You have to specify what you want to count: worst case, best case, average, etc.

Sometimes, you are interested in stating *asymptotic lower bounds* of (say) the worst case complexity. Then you write `f(n) = Omega(n^2)` to state that in the worst case, the complexity is *at least* `n^2`. The big-Omega notation is opposite to big-O: `f = Omega(g)` if and only if `g = O(f)`.

Answer (score 0):

Take [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) for an example. Each successive recursive call n of quicksort has a run-time complexity T(n) of

T(n) = O(n) + 2 T[ (n-1)/2 ]

in the 'best case' if the unsorted input list is splitted into two equal sublists of size (n-1)/2 in each call. Solving for T(n) gives O(n log n), in this case. If the partition is not perfect, and the two sublists are not of equal size n, i.e.

T(n) = O(n) + T(k) + T(n - 1 - k),

we still obtain O(n log n) even if k=1, just with a larger constant factor. This is because the number of recursive calls of quicksort is rising exponentially while processing the input list as long as k>0.

However, in the 'worst case' no division of the input list takes place, i.e.:

T(n) = O(n) + T(0) + T(n - 1) = O(n) + O(n-1) + T(n-1) + T(n-2) ... .

This happens e.g. if we take the first element of a sorted list as the pivot element.

Here, T(0) means one of the resulting sublists is zero and therefore takes no computing time (since the sublist has zero elements). All the remaining load T(n-1) is needed for the second sublist. In this case, we obtain O(n²).

If an algorithm had no worst case scenario, it would be not only be O[f(n)] but also o[f(n)] (Big-O vs. [little-o notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation)).

Comment: Your last sentence is just wrong. `O` and `o` are entirely unrelated to whether you're considering the worst case runtime of an algorithm. I'm not sure you understand what little `o` means (I think you're confusing it with `Θ`, which is also unrelated to worst caseness, but does tell you whether you have the "tightest" bound). For example the time it takes to iterated through an array of length `n` is in `O(n)` and `Θ(n)`, but not in `o(n)`.

Comment: Yeah, I think, I confused it with \Theta -- and, yes, on a second thought, it's also unrelated. But, anyway, as the answer states, the O-notation is just a measure and does not specify what is measured. This is a much more stringent explanation.

Answer (score -1):

The asymptotic bound is the expected behaviour as the number of operations go to infinity. Mathematically it is just that lim as n goes to infinity. The worst case behaviour however is  applicable to finite number of operations.